# Changing certain character of a string or character pointer in C++

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, immutability

I will really appreciate and remain grateful to him/her who can help me for helping me. It is similar in C/C++.

```
int string_length;
char *str;
str="Muhammad ashikuzzaman";
printf("%c",str[1]); 
str[1]='o'; // Here an Unhandled Exception occurred
printf("%c",str[1]);
```

At line 6 or may be in 5 an Unhandled Exception occurred and the output is not displaying. I need to change any certain character of the character pointer. Please help me.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. All of them. Don't come back until you've read them all.

Comment: `"Muhammad ashikuzzaman"` is a constant string; allocate memory and copy this string into it, then modify as needed.

Comment: Thanks @abiessu . I had allocate dynamic memory and got an solution.

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB I see from warnings and error list it is about memory and immutability of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int string_length;
char *str,*str2,ch;
str="Muhammad ashikuzzaman";
str2=str;
string_length=strlen(str);
str=(char*)malloc(string_length*sizeof(char));
for(int i=0;i<string_length;i++)
    {
     if(i==1)
     *(str+i)='o';
     else  *(str+i)=str2[i];
     } 
for(int i=0;i<string_length;i++)
    printf("%c",*(str+i));
```

Comment: This is not really good example code. A lot of unnecessary moving around and overwriting of variables. That last line could better be written as `printf ("%s", str);`, but even `str[i]` would have been (marginally) better than `*(str+i)`. (Also, you forgot to reserve space for the terminating 0. Your new `str` is *not* a proper C string.)

Comment: But when I write str[i] after my code it is also display some other ascii value after the name "Muhammad Ashikuzzaman 8◙♠♥•-▬♂" . I made a loop as i< string_length. and for char str[] = "Muhammad ashikuzzaman"; I am can not displaying through printf("%s",str); I am using Common Language Run Time (CLR) in visual studio. Thanks for informing me @Jongware. My happiness is that my problem is solved now by the help of friends from here.

Comment: On the weird characters: note my last sentence (I added it later so you might have missed it initially.)

Answer (score 7):

String literals are immutable in C and C++. That is any attempt to modify them result in undefined behaviour of the program. Instead of these statements

```
char *str;
str="Muhammad ashikuzzaman";
```

use this one

```
char str[] = "Muhammad ashikuzzaman";
```

As for your definition and initialization of pointer str then the correct code in C++ will look like

```
const char *str;
str="Muhammad ashikuzzaman";
```

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad from Moscow I had used dynamic memory allocation and got an exact solution..

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in c/c++/java/python.changing the certain character in string is not allowed.

```
Using character pointer strings is stored in two ways.
            1.Read only string in a shared segment.
            2.Dynamically allocated in heap segment.
```

when string value is assigned directly to a pointer,it is stored only in read only segment    that is shared among segments

```
            char *str = "Helloworld";
```

The above string "Helloworld" is stored in a shared read only location, but pointer str is stored in a read-write memory. You can change str to point something else but cannot change value at present str.

Source:http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-for-strings-in-c/?